# Difference between Nuget Package Installation and manual installation of Ajaxtoolkit

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit, nuget

May be my question is very silly but I searched over the Google but didnt get the proper answer of my question, my question is: I am installing `Ajaxtoolkit` for one of my project. The basic method i use to do it is to manually add`Ajaxtoolkit` to the Toolbar. I can do it through the NuGet Package Manager also. So i just wanted to know, Is their any difference between the manual and NuGet installation?

For example: When I tired to add `Ajaxtoolkit` to VS2012 manually I added the `Ajaxtoolkit` dll to the BIN folder and add the `Ajaxtoolkit` controls to the Toolbox but when I tried to add `Ajaxtoolkit` using NuGet Package Manager then so many dlls along with the `Ajaxtoolkit`, Ajaxmin and HtmlAgility was also installed in my BIN folder.

I am looking for the basic difference between both the ways of Installation of `Ajaxtoolkit` and what is recommended.?

Many Thanks for your answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the Ajaxtoolkit dll when you manually install it?

If you install via NuGet Package Manager, you may get extra files to your project that you don't need, but you also get the benefit of uninstalling the package cleanly from your project. Also if there is a newer version of the package (that may contain newer version of the Ajaxtoolkit dll) uploaded to https://www.nuget.org, your package manager will show the updated version automatically.

Comment: i have downloaded Ajaxtookit from codeplex http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/109918